# shadow.appendChild is slower in shadyDom

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, shady-dom

I am experimenting with WebComponents. I have used Shady DOM, to work with browsers which doesn't support Shadow DOM yet (Mozilla and IE).

I find that shadow.appendChild is significantly slower in ShadyDOM than in ShadowDOM.

Here are the JS Fiddles' for both Shadow DOM and Shady DOM.

Shady Dom : https://jsfiddle.net/lnaravindan/Lhrzapmt/3/

Have used

```
ShadyDOM = {force: true};
```

Shadow Dom : https://jsfiddle.net/lnaravindan/L74vju6m/4/

Have avoided ShadyDOM by

```
ShadowDOM = { force: false}; // Default setting
```

You can check the console in both fiddles for the time taken for appending content to the Shadow Root.

Average time for appending content to shadow for:

Shadow DOM is 0.06ms

Shady DOM is 0.65ms

Since I have a number of custom elements, this difference is accounting to much greater amount.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It's quite normal. Shadow DOM is native, while ShadyDOM no. The contrary would have been surprising.

Comment: @Supersharp Yeah I accept that. I didn't expect that it will be ~10x times slower than native implementation. Considering the case that I have 100's of custom elements, this difference will be huge. That's my concern.

Comment: Do you really need shadow dom? You can always use *normal* DOM for your 100s elements.

Comment: @Supersharp Two reasons for which I need shadow DOM are.

1. Scoped CSS. 
2. Slots.